# SQL collation for remove accents

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to remove accents from one column.

So i'm trying using this:

```
_latin1 COLUMN_NAME collate latin1_General_CS
```

But for "á" i get "Ã¡".

I also tried this but without success:

```
CONVERT ('á' USING cp1251)
```

Comment: What is your motivation for wanting to remove accents?

Comment: Look like you have a problem with the encoding of the output.

Answer (score 1):

Try SQL_Latin1_General_Cp1251_CS_AS

```
select 
    'informática' collate SQL_Latin1_General_Cp1251_CS_AS
```

Returns

```
informatica
```

Comment: Error: "Unknown collation: 'SQL_Latin1_General_Cp1251_CS_AS'"

Comment: Thats strange; according to Books online for SQL Server its supported on 2000,2005, 2008/r2 and 2012. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180175(v=sql.100).aspx is the column nvarchar/unicode

Comment: Ohh sorry i'm using Mysql 5.1.29